# keyboard obeserver ios

Tags: objective-c, uikeyboard

I have a `UIView` and i'm trying to make it follow the keyboard when the user move the keyboard. imagine the user having a `scrollview` and a open keyboard, the user want to scroll down which makes the keyboard to close half way, the keyboard `origin.y` change. the problem is when the keyboard is open and moving no event is being called else you literally close the keyboard.
I tried using the keyboard delegate + textfield delegate which is:

```
* UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
* UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
* UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
* UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
* UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
* textFieldDidBeginEditing:
* textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
* textFieldDidEndEditing:
* textFieldShouldEndEditing:
```

All those methods are being called only when keyboard is about to open/dismiss and what is happening is that when the user is moving the keyboard the `UIView` wont move as it wait for one of those observers to be called.

What i am basically looking for is a way to observe the keyboard `origin.y` (shown height) whenever its value change

Comment: do you want to move your view when keyboard appears?

Comment: @AgentChocks. i want to move my view when the keyboard moves, as when the keyboard is open and the user move it up and down but dont really close it.

Comment: have you seen this https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: the project is based on UIKeyboard events / UITextField events

Answer (score -1):

Put this code below

```
 #import

    static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
    static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
    static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
    static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
    static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 140;

 textfieldDelegate

  - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
        {
            CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
            CGRect viewRect = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];
            CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
            CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
            CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height;
            CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;
            if (heightFraction < 0.0)
            {
                heightFraction = 0.0;
            }
            else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
            {
                heightFraction = 1.0;
            }
            UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
            if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
                orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
            {
                animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
            }
            else
            {
                animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
            }
            CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
            viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
            [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
        - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
        {
            CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
            viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
            [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
        -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField
        {
            NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
            // Try to find next responder
            UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
            if (nextResponder)
            {        
                // Found next responder, so set it.
                [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
            }
            else
            {
                //Not found, so remove keyboard.
                [textField resignFirstResponder];

            }
            return NO; // We  // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
        }
```

Comment: this code is basing on textfield events and not the keyboard Y value. if for example i try to scroll down (moving my finger swiping the keyboard down but not closing it) nothing will happen

Comment: Don't hardcode keyboard sizes. The keyboard can change sizes - what if the user has the autocomplete suggestion bar showing, or there's an accessory view? Which devices have this magical keyboard size?